# How do I extract JSON data from a PHP file?

Tags: php, json, variables, passwords

I've got an external php file containing the following data:

```
<?php

/*|[{"username":"user","password":"password","project":"Template"}]|*/

?>
```

How do I pass the password element into the variable $password? Using my own php script?

Please note that the content of this PHP file has surrounded itself with a comment and pipe symbol. How do I go about removing these so that loading the file adds the json rather than ignoring it.

Comment: REad the file, store the contents in a string and use json decode. Ull get an array with 'password' as key

Comment: The php file json is surrounded by quotations and a pipe set. It's not allowing the data to go into the process.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use the `json_decode()` function:

```
//$str = file_get_contents('path/to/phpFile.php');

$str = '<?php

/*|[{"username":"user","password":"password","project":"Template"}]|*/

?>';

$str = preg_replace('/<\?php\s{0,}\/\*\||\|\*\/\s{0,}\?>/', '', $str); //<--removes unwanted stuff.

$myArray = json_decode($str, true);

$username = $myArray[0]['username'];
$password = $myArray[0]['password'];

echo $username . '<br>';
echo $password . '<br>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($myArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank you this was a great example and works well with the $str version.

However the PHP file I'm using appears to have surrounded itself with a comment and | character. I don't know why, this is just how the open source project i'm trying to interface with works.

This means that when I load the file, there's basically nothing for the json_decode to decode because all it see's is a comment.

Comment: @Daniel Foreman Ok run the current code, should work now.